# Too many conditions in the method

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js and I am just wondering what you think about this code. For me, it seems there are too many conditions in the code. Is there any way to refactor it?

```
  var removeQuestions = function(questions) {
    if (questions.length < 1)
      return;

    var group_name = questions[0].group;
    var metagroup_name = questions[0].metagroup;

    // update count in groups
    QuestionGroupModel.find({group: group_name}).exec(function(err, groups) {
      if(!err) {
        groups[0].cnt = groups[0].cnt - questions.length;

        if(groups[0].cnt > 0) {
          groups[0].save(function(err2) {
            if(err2)
              console.info('error while updating group info');
            });
        } else {
          QuestionGroupModel.find({group: groups[0].group}).remove(function(err3) {
            if(!err3) {
              console.info('groups %s was deleted', groups[0].group);
            } else {
              console.info('error while deleting group');
            }
          });
        }
      } else {
        console.info('error while lookup group info');
      };
    });

    // delete questions
    for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
      QuestionModel.remove({ _id: questions[i]._id }, function(err) {
        if(!err) {
          log.info("question removed");
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

Almost all of your conditions are error handling, so there's not a lot to clean up.  For clarity's sake, I would make your initial error handler a guard condition, which makes it much more obvious what's going on.  I would then break out all your inner functions into labeled functions, which makes it clear what you're trying to achieve:

```
QuestionGroupModel.find({group: group_name}).exec(function(err, groups) {
    if (err) {
        console.info("Error while lookup group info", err);
        return;
    }

    var deleteGroup = function(group) {
        QuestionGroupModel.find({group: groups[0].group}).remove(function(err) {
            console.info.apply(null, (err) ? ['error while deleting group', err] : ['groups %s was deleted', group]);
        });
    };

    var saveGroup = function(group) {
        group.save(function(err2) {
            if(err2)
                console.info('error while updating group info');
        });
    };

    groups[0].cnt = groups[0].cnt - questions.length;

    if (groups[0].cnt > 0) {
        saveGroup(groups[0]);  // That you have two different arguments for similar operations is a code smell.
    } else {
        deleteGroup(groups[0].group);
    }
});
```

I don't have a clear picture of your QuestionGroupModel, but that they take different arguments for similar operations shows that the model itself has problems, and may require refactoring.